# Restrict User For Folder Access in php

Tags: php

I am new in php i want to restrict user for folder access user can not access my images folder and i have one thumb folder in that images folder what should i do for that.

exammple :- i have one folder **_cat_img** and in that i have one more folder that name is t**humb.** i want to restrict user for both folders
     i am try to use code with .htaccess but it's not working.
    i am using this in htaccess

```
    **Deny from All**
```

but it is restrict all folders what should i do to to restrict user for particular folder access any one help me for this

Answer (score 0):

Use `Directory` apache directive for specifying a particular directory. Then give access directives (allow or deny) inside it.

```
<Directory "fullpath/_cat_img">
 Order Deny,allow
 Deny from all
</Directory>


<Directory "full_path/thumb">
 Order Deny,allow
 Deny from all
</Directory>
```

**Edit**

To activate .htaccess edit your apache conf and inside virtual host section of your website add these.

```
<Directory documnet_root>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart apache.

Comment: not working because i have one folder "aanshi" but use this code in htaccess but now i can not open my aanshi folder

Comment: That's what I meant by full path.